# NuxtJS + TailwindCSS with JIT + Vite

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, vite

I'm trying to install NuxtJS + TailwindCSS with Jit + Vite, it works but I have some issues annoying.

In every change that I do, appear the next error:

```
 WARN  Unrestricted file system access to "/@id/defaultexport:/Users/mac/Nuxt/testing/.nuxt/components/plugin.js"


 WARN  For security concerns, accessing files outside of serving allow list will be restricted by default in the future version of Vite. Refer to https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-fs-allow for more details.


 WARN  Unrestricted file system access to "/@id/defaultexport:/Users/mac/Nuxt/testing/.nuxt/axios.js"


 WARN  Unrestricted file system access to "/@id/__x00__/vite/vueComponentNormalizer"


 WARN  Unrestricted file system access to "/@id/__x00__/vite/vueHotReload"


 WARN                                                                    23:01:50


 WARN  warn - You have enabled the JIT engine which is currently in preview.


 WARN  warn - Preview features are not covered by semver, may introduce breaking changes, and can change at any time.
```

I need to stop server and start it again and all works correctly. But then, I do a change again and it broke and need restart again.

I just follow the instructions from Nuxt website. Something that I'm missing?

Comment: Did you tried to look into the issues for each of the errors?

Comment: With adding { server: { fs: { strict: false } } in `vite.config.js` work for you ?  (https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-fs-strict)

Comment: @flydev, adding { server: { fs: { strict: false } } in vite.config.js not work for me

Comment: @AlauddinAfifCassandra if you have the exact same issue, please provide a reproducible repo as I didn't saw last time the `vueHotReload` import which is causing for sure issue on @Carloscito problem. Try : 
```import { defineConfig, searchForWorkspaceRoot } from 'vite'```
```export default defineConfig({"server":{"fs":{"allow":["searchForWorkspaceRoot(process.cwd())"]}}})```